# Retrieving Variable Importance from Caret trained model with "lda2", "qda", "lda"

Tags: r, r-caret

I can get variable importance out from "nnet" and "knn" models, but not from "lda", "lda2", and "qda".

I am using varImp(). I've tried everything I can think of and just can't get a proper idea of what the variable importance is.

Here is my code for training the model:

```
lda_model <- train(quality2 ~ ., 
                   data = train_data,
                   method = "lda",
                   preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                            number = 10,
                                            repeats = 2),
                   importance = TRUE)
```

and here is the error I get when I try to check importance:

```
> varImp(lda_model)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I know this means it's treating it as an object class list instead of a trained model, and I've tried it on lda_model$finalmodel and others, but it's still not working.

How can I get proper feedback when using lda/qda on how my model is performing and which variables are performing best?

Comment: What are the values of `quality2`?

Comment: Since no information is given, I assume `quality2` is a factor with numeric values. Try converting the numeric values to characters.

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply, quality2 is a factor with levels 0 and 1

Comment: I will try to change it to a character

Comment: @quality2 sadly that didn't help, I tried both as characters, numerics and as factor numerics and wouldn't work

Comment: Could you reproduce this problem with an inbuilt data set or alternatively create some fake data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I experienced the issue on multiple PCs with inbuilt dataset fgl as well. It seems to not work on some PCs and laptops, but work on others. It is now working on my laptop after updating some packages. I use university PCs which work on an older version of R , but use the new version of packages (it says warning built on 3.5.1 for example), so I am guessing there is some minor issue that is causing it to fail. However sometimes on the university PCs it works, I cannot figure out what the differences are

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems to come from the way of the dataset is imported in R. I first imported with the {readxl} package and varImp() didn't work. Then I tried to import throught the clipboard and now varImp is working on my lda model build with {caret}.

My code with {readxl} :

```
library(readxl)
glauc <- read_excel("Glaucome.xlsx", sheet="GlaucomaM")
rownames(glauc) <- glauc$IDENT
glauc$IDENT <- NULL
glauc$Class <- as.factor(glauc$Class)

library(caret)
numappr <- createDataPartition(glauc$Class, p=0.7)
appr <- glauc[numappr$Resample1,]
test <- glauc[-numappr$Resample1,]

Ctrl <- trainControl(summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs=TRUE)
appr.lda <- train(Class~., data=appr, method="lda",
                  trControl=Ctrl, preProc = c("center","scale"),
                  metric="ROC")
varImp(appr.lda)
```

This leads to the same error message as yours.

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

And my code with read.table() and the clipboard :

```
glauc <- read.table("clipboard", header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
rownames(glauc) <- glauc$IDENT
glauc$IDENT <- NULL

library(caret)
numappr <- createDataPartition(glauc$Class, p=0.7)
appr <- glauc[numappr$Resample1,]
test <- glauc[-numappr$Resample1,]

Ctrl <- trainControl(summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs=TRUE)
appr.lda <- train(Class~., data=appr, method="lda",
                  trControl=Ctrl, preProc = c("center","scale"),
                  metric="ROC")
varImp(appr.lda)
```

This one leads to the result (only the first ones here):

```
varImp(appr.lda)
ROC curve variable importance

  only 20 most important variables shown (out of 62)

     Importance
vari     100.00
varg      97.14
vars      94.52
phci      93.69
hic       92.02
phcg      90.55
tms       89.96
```

Hope it helps.

Sophie

Comment: For me, the solution was to convert my `tibble` to a `data.frame` using `as.data.frame` before passing it on to `varImp`. I think using `data.table` defaults to a dataframe, so it works in the end.